# Is there a method available to convert the web3 PublicKey to metaplex's publicKey?

Tags: mpl-token-metadata, umi

I'm using both libraries in my codebase.

Whenever I pass a pubkey to an metaplex method, I sometimes need to convert:

example

```
import { Umi, publicKey } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi';
import { findAssociatedTokenPda } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-toolbox';

~~~~~~~

  const mint = publicKey(mintPublicKey.toBase58());
  const walletAddress = publicKey(wallet.publicKey.toBase58());
  const owner = findAssociatedTokenPda(umi, {
    mint,
    owner: walletAddress,
  });
```

Is there a built in method so that I don't have to convert to base58 and then call the publicKey fn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert the public keys, use the `fromWeb3JsPublicKey` and `toWeb3JsPublicKey` methods from the `@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters` package.

You can read more on the documentation about the [Web3.js adapters](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/umi/blob/main/docs/web3js-adapters.md) in the Umi GitHub repo.